# What is said on the Chinese broadcast 34 minutes into Looper?

Tags: dialogue, looper

At 34:00, we briefly see a television depicting mass-destruction and the English words 'Rainmaker'. What is being said in Chinese on this newscast?

Comment: Someone is trying to help you! 

http://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/10674/what-is-being-said-in-this-scene-from-looper

Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

X-post from [chinese.stackexchange](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/10675/9214) - courtesy of [Andrew Martin](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/users/6996/andrew-martin), [Lei Chen](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/users/6998/lei-chen), and with help from [Jordan McBride](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/16194/jordan-mcbride)

> The dialog says: "随着神秘的Rainmaker在中西部的暴乱事件中继续他的帮派战争, ..."
>
> My translation is : "As the mysterious Rainmaker continues his gang
>   war in the Midwest, ..."